# Как написать статический блок инициализации в суперклассе, чтобы в наследниках использовать статические поля

Tags: java, наследование, статические-члены

Для этого потребуется в родительском классе:

1. Объявить статическое поле
   String tableName.
2. Написать статический блок инициализации,
   в котором инициализируется это поле. Для этого потребуется ссылка на класс наследника. Как в статическом контексте получить ссылку на класс наследника?
   Ведь я же не могу применять слово this.
   Мне нужно получить ссылку на класс наследника. Затем с помощью рефлексии получить аннотацию @Table у класса наследника, чтобы получить значение параметров name и schema у этой аннотации.
   Конкатенация значений параметров schema + name у аннотации @Table у класса наследника будет присвоена полю tableName.
   Эту реализацию хочу написать в родительском классе для того, чтобы просто обращаться к полю класса наследника.
   Например вот так:
   MonitorinCertificate.tableName.
   Я не знаю, как в статическом блоке инициализации в родительском классе получить ссылку на класс наследника.

Родительский класс

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    public static String tableName;

    static {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: а слова `static::` там у вас никакого в вашем языке нет?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните язык программирования, на котором вы пишите =). Очень похоже на `java`

Comment: Вы никак не можете решить эту проблему: статические инициализаторы базового класса вызываются в тот момент когда нет никаких экземпляров классов-наследников. Вообще статики и наследование как вода и масло - не смешиваются.

Comment: Похоже на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). Какую задачу вы на самом деле пытаетесь решить? Для чего каждому объекту из БД знать свою схему+таблицу?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы по какой-то причине хотите на уровне интерфейса обязать классы знать свою таблицу, лучше выразить это через паттерн Шаблонный метод, а сами значения вынести в костанты во избежание дублирования.

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
    @NotNull abstract String getName();
    @NotNull abstract String getSchema();

    public String getTableName() { return getSchema() + getName(); }
}

@Table(schema = MonitoringCertificate.SCHEMA, name = MonitoringCertificate.TABLE)
class MonitoringCertificate extends BaseEntity {
    static final String SCHEMA = "foo";
    static final String TABLE = "bar";

    @NotNull @Override String getName() { return TABLE; }
    @NotNull @Override String getSchema() { return SCHEMA;}
}
```

---

Но, с большой вероятностью, гораздо полезнее будет один раз просканировать аннотации и сложить все в `Map<Class<?>, String>`, где у каждого класса будет уже склеенная строка.

Answer (score 1):

Вы формулируете условие вашей задачи так, что она становится бессмысленной. Причина простая: статика и наследование не пересекаются от слова совсем. Разумеется, невыполнимых задач нет. И если уж из статики вы никак не можете обратиться к нестатическим методам и полям, то наоборот это вполне возможно. Если предположить, что для всех сущностей у вас будет единственный супер класс (чтобы в этом был хоть какой-то смысл), то можно сделать примерно так:

```
abstract class BaseEntity {
    
    private final static String BASE_PACKAGE_NAME = "base.package.name";
    private final static String SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER = ".";
    
    private final static Map<Class, String> MAP = scan();

    public String getTableName() {        
        return MAP.get(this.getClass());
    }
    
    private static Map<Class, String> scan() {
        Map<Class, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new Reflections(BASE_PACKAGE_NAME).getTypesAnnotatedWith(Table.class);
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            Table annotation = (Table) clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class);
            if (annotation == null) continue;
            String tableName = annotation.schema().isEmpty() ? 
                    annotation.name() : annotation.schema() + SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER + annotation.name();
            result.put(clazz, tableName);
        }
        return result;
    }

}

@Table(schema = "test_schema", name = "b_name")
class A extends BaseEntity{}

@Table(name = "b_name")
class B extends BaseEntity{}
```

Лично для меня это выглядит как костыль))
Даже если что-то подобное нужно реализовать, то уж точно этого не нужно делать в супер классе. Гораздо проще и логичнее делинировать это стороннему классу, который просканирует весь проект на старте, подготовит все данные и будет единым источником, где это можно запросить для любого объекта.
Кроме того, можно 2навешать" перегруженные методы (в зависимоти от задачи), где, к примеру, будет подставляться дефолтная схема в случае ее отсутствия в аннотации.
Выглядит это примерно так:

```
import com.geeks.rea.model.History;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.reflections.Reflections;

public class ReflectionUtil {
    
    private final static String BASE_PACKAGE_NAME = "base.package.name";
    private final static String SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER = ".";    
    private final static Map<Class, String> MAP = scan();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTableName(History.class));
    }

    public static Optional<String> getTableName(Object entity) {        
        return Optional.ofNullable(MAP.get(entity.getClass()));
    }

    public static Optional<String> getTableName(Object entity, String defaultSchemaName) {
        if (defaultSchemaName == null || defaultSchemaName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Default schemas name can't be NULL");
        }
        else return getTableName(entity).map(name -> name.contains(SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER) ? 
                name : defaultSchemaName.trim() + SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER + name);
    }
    
    private static Map<Class, String> scan() {
        Map<Class, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new Reflections(BASE_PACKAGE_NAME).getTypesAnnotatedWith(Table.class);
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            Table annotation = (Table) clazz.getAnnotation(Table.class);
            if (annotation == null) continue;
            String tableName = annotation.schema().isEmpty() ? 
                    annotation.name() : annotation.schema() + SCHEMA_NAME_DELIMETER + annotation.name();
            result.put(clazz, tableName);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

P.S. для упрощения реализации рефлексии использовалась библиотека, которую можно найти здесь:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections

Не забудьте указать в переменной BASE_PACKAGE_NAME базовое имя своего пакета